# Array not Repopulating

Tags: excel, vba

In my Excel file, I have 10 worksheets representing the months from September until June. After downloading a csv file and sorting the data (by month and then by day), I add the range for each month to an array using the following code.

```vb
Function findLastRow(ws As Worksheet, column As String) As Integer 
    findLastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, column).End(xlUp).row
End Function

Function searchColumn(ws As Worksheet, column As String, value As Integer) As Boolean
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim search As String
    Dim startRow As Integer
    Dim endRow As Integer
    
    Set rng = ws.Range("J2:J" & findLastRow(ws, column))

    Set cell = rng.Find(what:=value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)
    
    If cell Is Nothing Then
        searchColumn = False
    Else
        searchColumn = True
    End If
End Function

Sub UpdateAttendance()
    Dim attendanceArr As Variant
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 10 To 10
        nameCheck = False
        
        If searchColumn(attendanceSheet, "J", i) = True Then
            With attendanceSheet
                startRow = .Range("J1:J" & findLastRow(attendanceSheet, "J")).Find(what:=i, after:=.Range("J1")).row
                endRow = .Range("J1:J" & findLastRow(attendanceSheet, "J")).Find(what:=i, after:=.Range("J1"), searchdirection:=xlPrevious).row
            End With
            
            attendanceArr = Range("A" & startRow & ":" & attendanceSheetLastLetter & endRow)
                
            Select Case i
            
                Case 1
                    populateAttendance ThisWorkbook.Sheets("January"), attendanceArr
                   
                Case 2 
                    populateAttendance ThisWorkbook.Sheets("February"), attendanceArr
                    
                Case 3
                    populateAttendance ThisWorkbook.Sheets("March"), attendanceArr
                    populateAttendance ThisWorkbook.Sheets("April"), attendanceArr
                    
                Case 5
                    populateAttendance ThisWorkbook.Sheets("May"), attendanceArr
                    
                Case 6
                    populateAttendance ThisWorkbook.Sheets("June"), attendanceArr
                    
                Case 9
                    populateAttendance ThisWorkbook.Sheets("September"), attendanceArr
                    
                Case 10 
                    populateAttendance ThisWorkbook.Sheets("October"), attendanceArr
                    
                Case 11
                    populateAttendance ThisWorkbook.Sheets("November"), attendanceArr
                    
                Case 12
                    populateAttendance ThisWorkbook.Sheets("December"), attendanceArr
                   
            End Select
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

When I step through the code, it skips the Cases 1 through 8 (January to August) which is what it is supposed to do.
When i is 9 (September), it successfully executes the sub populateAttendance.

When i is 10 (October), it successfully detects the startRow and endRow (it states the row that 10 begins with is 1302 and ends at row 2211 which is correct).
It then executes the attendanceArr line and the result is

[image]

The array is empty. However, when I change the For loop to `For i = 10 To 10`, focus on just October, the macro works.

Comment: Have you tried debugging?  Are you getting the expected values for startRow/endRow for example?

Comment: The small amount of code you've provided does not give us all the information you've described in the problem, including the definition (size, dimensions) of the array, how `i` is iterated and then used as an index, etc.  Please edit the question to show more of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all `Case 4` is missing! But note that instead of the entire `Select Case i` block (with a lot of repeating code) you can just use the following:

```
' define this before your for loop starts
Dim MonthsList As Variant
MonthsList = Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "September", "October", "November", "December")
```

Put this line instead of the entire `Select Case i … End Select` block:

```
populateAttendance ThisWorkbook.Sheets(MonthsList(i - 1)), attendanceArr
```

---

Note that here

```
attendanceArr = Range("A" & startRow & ":" & attendanceSheetLastLetter & endRow)
```

it is not defined in which sheet that `Range` is, therefore it might pick the wrong sheet and if this sheet is epmty your array is empty. Use something more specific like:

```
attendanceArr = attendanceSheet.Range("A" & startRow & ":" & attendanceSheetLastLetter & endRow).Value
```

**Always** define in which sheet a range has to be found or Excel has the chance to pick the wrong sheet.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback and everything works perfectly.  Take Care.